# Proving the generalized intersection of the interval (0, 1/n) is the empty set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that the generalized intersection of the interval (0,1/n) is the empty set?

Aka prove that $(0,1) \cap (0, 1/2) \cap (0, 1/3) \cap (0, 1/4) ... = \emptyset$.

I know that I need to prove this by contradiction, by assuming that there exists an x in the intersection and then choosing a positive integer n s.t. 1/n < x.

I'm having trouble putting it all together, especially since I'm supposed to use this fact: For all x in R, there exists k in N s.t. k > x.

When I flip this around, I get that 1/k < 1/x, which isn't what I want. I understand how and why the proof works, I just can't seem to format it with enough rigor.

Answer (score 4):

Actually it **is** what you want! You just need to be a bit clever about what to set as $x$.

If you suppose $x_0\in A$ (where $A$ is the intersection) with $x_0>0$, then if we let $x=\frac{1}{x_0}$, there is some $k\in\mathbb{N}^+$ with $k>x\implies k>\frac{1}{x_0}$ which implies that there is some $\frac{1}{k}\in\mathbb{Q}^+$ with $\frac{1}{k}<x_0$.

Comment: I understand how you completed the proof with setting $x$ to be as such, although i am confused and how this proves the intersection to be empty. could you supply some clarification? where is the contradiction?

Comment: to finish, $x_0$ is therefore not in the set $(0,\frac{1}{k})$ and so it cannot be in the intersection. It follows that no $x_0>0$ can be in $A$, hence $A$ is empty.

Comment: i formulated my own proof (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2444903/help-finishing-archimedean-property-proof/2444917#2444917) using the concepts in this one. is my proof correct?

Comment: @rover2 Yes. Your proof is equivalent to Dan Rust's proof.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there is $x_0 \in A$ where $A$ is the intersection, then there is some $n_0$ where $x_0 = \frac{1}{n_0}$. But then there is some $n > n_0$ that $x = \frac{1}{n} < x_0$, a contradiction.