# Infinite intersection of the interval$ (0,\frac{1}{n})$ is not empty, because...

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Imagine the infinite intersection of $(-\frac{1}{2n},\frac{1}{2n})$ is $\{0\}$.

And the length of both open intervals $(0,\frac{1}{n})$ and $(-\frac{1}{2n},\frac{1}{2n})$ are the same.

So, if $(-\frac{1}{2n},\frac{1}{2n})$ approaches $\{0\}$ which is not empty, so must $(0,\frac{1}{n})$ do.

Thus the infinte intersection of the interval $(0,\frac{1}{n})$ is not empty.

Is it right?

Comment: What do you mean when you say _"the topological property of ($0$,$\frac{1}{n}$) and (-$\frac{1}{2n}$,$\frac{1}{2n}$) is same."_?

Comment: I mean the length of the two intervals..

Comment: But how would that be an argument to say $0$ is in the intersection? It is not (see answers below).

Comment: they are embeded sequence of intervals and of the same lengh for every n. I'm just curious.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. Note that for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, you have $0 \in \left(-\tfrac{1}{2n},\tfrac{1}{2n} \right)$ but $0 \notin \left(0,\tfrac{1}{n} \right)$.

You can also take a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/588517/proving-the-generalized-intersection-of-the-interval-0-1-n-is-the-empty-set).

Answer (score 2):

No, Because $0$ is not a common point of the intervals $\left(0,\frac{1}{n} \right)$ .

Comment: It's always divide by zero error. Every. Time.