# Help Finishing Archimedean Property Proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-explanation

Prove ${\bigcap}_{n=1}^\infty$ $(0, \displaystyle\frac{1}{n})$ $= \emptyset$.

In order to show that this intersection is equal to $\emptyset$, we need to show there is no element, $x$, in the intersection. Suppose there does exist such an $x\in (0, \displaystyle\frac{1}{n})$. Then $0<x<\frac{1}{n}$. Archimediean Property states that for any $x\in \mathbb{R}, \exists n \in \mathbb{N}$, such that $n>x$. This gives us that $\frac{1}{n}<\frac{1}{x}$. Let A represent the intersection and $x_0 \in A, x_0 >0$. Then $0<x_0<\frac{1}{n}$. If we set $x=\frac{1}{x_0}$, then $\frac{1}{n} < x_0$. This is a contrradiction since $x_0 < \frac{1}{n}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that the intersection is not empty, i.e., there exists $x$ in this intersection. Because every interval $(0,1/n)$ contains only strictly positive numbers, $x$ must be strictly positive as well. But for every $x>0$ there exists $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $1/n<x$. For this number $n$ it is the case that $x\not\in(0,1/n)$. Hence, $x$ is not in the intersection. Contradiction.

Comment: how does it follow immediately?

Comment: I don't use induction. If you want to show that the intersection is empty, you only need to show that for every $x$ there exists at least one $n$ such that $x\not\in(0,1/n)$. For every $x>0$ there exists $n$ such that $1/n<x$. Hence, $x$ is not in the corresponding set $(0,1/n)$.

Comment: i just edited my proof above, did i understand how to finish it?